# Adding items dynamically to the list using foreach loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have model `InvoiceViewModel` which has a property Items which is a list. I want to run `foreach` on Items property and add it dynamically to the list.

***InvoiceViewModel.cs***

```
public class InvoiceViewModel
{
    ...
    public List<ItemsViewModel> Items { get; set; }

}
```

***ItemsViewModel.cs***

```
public class ItemsViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the following code to add Items from InvoiceViewModel dyanmically to the list.

```
    var Items = InvoiceViewModel.Items;
    var ItemsList = new List<ItemsViewModel>
    {
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            new ItemsViewModel { Name = item.Name, UnitPrice = item.UnitPrice, Quantity = item.Quantity, TotalAmount = item.TotalAmount };
        }
    };
```

The above code is throwing error, `} expected`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay. So, you are looping inside of an object which is syntactically wrong to do. When you initialize a List, the Object initializer expects you to provide a list of the T class. What you should do is:

```
var ItemsList = new List<ItemsViewModel>();

foreach (var item in InvoiceViewModel.Items)
{
    ItemsList.Add(new ItemsViewModel { Name = item.Name, UnitPrice = item.UnitPrice, Quantity = item.Quantity, TotalAmount = item.TotalAmount });
}
```

Or you can use LINQ expressions to initialize the object something like this:

```
var ItemsList = InvoiceViewModel.Items
                .Select(item => new ItemsViewModel { Name = item.Name, UnitPrice = item.UnitPrice, Quantity = item.Quantity, TotalAmount = item.TotalAmount })
                .ToList();
```